# Generate a temporary thumbnail image at time of http request

Tags: php, image

I want to present a thumbnail image of a video file on a webpage, which would be a link to the corresponding video file stored on the webserver. I could generate and store the thumbnail images ahead of time, but I don't have much disk space and traffic will be extremely light so I'm looking to generate the thumbnail image on the fly when the page is loaded.

While I don't have much/any experience, I should be able to build a thumbnail image on the fly using ffmpeg and PHP without too much difficulty. However, I'm not sure how I should manage the thumbnail files after they're built and no longer being used. I suppose I could have a simple job periodically delete the thumbnail files from the file system, but that seems like a bit of a kludge. Is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: The most elegant solution is the one you're trying to rule out; store the images on the server without involving PHP. You have space for videos but not images? Thumbnails like this would be a matter of kilobytes, normally.

Comment: Maybe you could just upload the photo, convert the photo to base64 string, display the string on the page, and after that delete the photo. So everytime page load, it will repeat the process. But i'm not sure if this work though.

Answer (score 0):

if you know your way around ffmpeg i would go with this somewhere before sending the page to the user.:

1. make the thumbnails from the video using exec(ffmpeg..)
2. store the just created image somewhere on the server.
3. Do as @Afif said, get the base 64 string and add it into your html
4. delete the thumbnail using unlink($filename);

Be aware of user permission on reading and wrting file. I know ffmpeg is a power full tool but maybe you canf ind your way around with this:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

This will consume space as wel but you could also blob the thumbnail in your database. Therefore be able to delete it later on. Even more you could add an 'last used' value a make a delete statement for everyhing not bieng used after a certian amount of time. run it as cron or make a sql trigger.